How would I vertically align InputProps endAdornment to bottom
I want to position 2 buttons to bottom of endAdornment
This is what I have currently:

          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position='end' sx={{ position: 'relative', bottom: 0 }}>
                <Button variant='contained' color="secondary" size='small'>
                  {t('cancel')}
                </Button>
                <Button variant='contained' type='submit' size='small'>
                  {!loading && t('comment')} {loading && <CircularProgress size={35}/>}
                </Button>
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}

Additionally I would like to use the unused white space above the buttons after they're positioned at bottom.
I've tried doing this:
  <div sx={{position: 'relative'}}>
        <InputAdornment sx={{position: 'absolute', top: 0}}>
    ///icons
        </InputAdornment>
  </div>

In InputProps but it does not work as expected
